# Azure Secret Web.config Transform with Github deploy

Tags: .net, azure, connection-string, asp.net-identity

I'm using [ElCamino's Azure Identity Storage](https://identityazuretable.codeplex.com/) for my site hosted as a Azure Web App.

For deployment I've got Azure watching the Github repository. The repository is public.

My issue is that I would like to store the connection string/key for Azure Storage in Azure and have it inserted into the Web.config at deployment. ElCamino uses the Web.config element `elcaminoIdentityConfiguration` in its own config section. I've seen the connection string and appSettings options under config for the web app, but I haven't been able to figure out how to securely store an arbitrary web.config transform when deploying from a public Github repo.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it cannot be done at the moment. [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu), the app that does the build & and deploy doesn't apply web.config transforms, therefore not allowing you to have custom configuration sections.

The only way to manage secrets is with the AppSettings - https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Managing-settings-and-secrets